# three table inner join with empty table for searching

Tags: php, mysql, join

my database is structured as below
[image: four tables]

at present the character, groups and vault tables all have data. The games tables is empty however.

Is it possible to write an inner join on the games table that will allow for a php search box to get data from the other three tables even though the games table has no data in it?

Is there another way of doing this that I might not know about?

For example I want to write a php search script for a webpage that searches on the games tables. If a user enters 'Allistair Tenpenny', it will pull the data from the characters table and display it in the search page with the characters name and their history, same with if some one searches a vault it will display the data from the vaults table.

From what I have read of inner joins the data on each joined table must match for it to display. Is there another way to approach this?

[image: charactor table]
[image: vault table]

Comment: You're question doesn't really make sense, but I will try to comment. You can have joins to show all data (from either or both tables), so the last sentence isn't true. From the fourth paragraph I assume you just want the script to search all tables using the search string. In that case their are other ways to do that.

Comment: @davejal how else would I go about this? As you said I can do it a different way? I was trying to do it via a many to many table.

Comment: Not sure if you want to search all tables and get results from all other tables but from just one. The solution provided by @Sgt AJ is almost what I was thinking of, but then again, this will only show data from 1 table and will require 3 buttons instead of 1 (easier for the user). From the comments below I'm still not sure what you want exactly, but I will write some plan you could use as an answer.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some data you have and what you want to search for and what the result would be.

Comment: @davejal I am trying to find a way to be able to search all three tables at once and return the data relevant to the search I am also trying to do it with a many to many table as well. So the search function is built on the games table, if a user enters a charactors name it pulls the data from the charactors tables.

Comment: If a user can get data of an existing character, there should be information about an existing game. Why is the table empty? Has it accidentally lost its data?

Comment: @davejal I added images of data in the tables to show as requested.

Comment: Check my answer, it has a solid solution for you if you want just 1 button (user doesn't need to know where it will be searching) Otherwise the solution given by @Ausghostdog is a good way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No inner join is necessary to get the data you want.  You can simply use php to use SQL to search the appropriate table based on the user input.

If there are multiple search fields on your page, just name the submit buttons differently, then have PHP check for the existence of each submit button's POST data from the form, then perform the appropriate search.  An example form might be:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Search Character Name:<input type="text" name="charactername">
    <input type="submit" name="charsubmit" value="Search">
</form>
<form action="" method="post">
    Search Vault Name:<input type="text" name="vaultname">
    <input type="submit" name="vaultsubmit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Your PHP code can then be structured as:

```
if (isset($_POST['charsubmit']))
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM character_table WHERE character_name = ':mydata'");
    $stmt->bindParam(':mydata',$_POST['charactername']);
}
elseif (isset($_POST['vaultsubmit']))
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM vault_table WHERE vault_name = ':mydata'");
    $stmt->bindParam(':mydata',$_POST['vaultname']);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

Using prepared statements like this is a good way to prevent SQL injection attacks, thus ensuring user entered data is **NEVER** put directly into a SQL statement.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information I will play around with this and will also add the sanitizing to stop people from dropping a table.

Comment: as you already said it yourself, never put user data... Then why don't you update your code to show a pdo example? But this is something the OP can work with

Comment: @Ausghostdog - You should use prepared statements. See [sqlsrv_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php)

Comment: Code updated to show prepared statements.  I didn't want anyone learning to do it the wrong way from my example.

Comment: @SgtAJ - Good decision so far (+1), you should be more verbose when using `PDO` instead of `sqlsrv` as the PO did, or just write prepared statements in `sqlsrv`.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it yourself. There should be no redundant information in normalized relative database. All the data tables have a column `history`. It should not have redundant data, which you could use to identify rows in other tables, but a description of the record set in the own table. We don't know, what `vault_number` is for. All other tables might be connected to the `vault` table directly depending on your data structure. Only you know, what your intention building this structure has been.

Further more you have connected `games` to `groups` by a redundant column with the `group_name`. You should avoid any redundancy and give the `groups` an `id`. Then connect it to `games` by a foreign `group_id` key. Imagine what will happen, when there are 100 games in a group and you decide to rename a group or just want to correct a typo.

Comment: This gives some explanation (mostly about normalization and db 101), but doesn't provide an answer.

Comment: Each history column contains different information, so you are saying I should name each history column something differnt? I could also drop vault number from all other tables other than the vault table. I could also rename the the group_name to group ID, would that help?

Comment: @Ausghostdog - No, that's not, what I'm saying. There may remain equal named colums in each table. The content should not be duplicate. If it is designed in non normalized way, you might be able to link the tables by that information. Then you should do so only to generate the missing data in games and normalize the structure after that. If your question is just: "Can I read the other tables when creating a new game entry", then the answer is: Just do it without any join. Let the user or random number generator select one entry and store the ID with the new entry to be inserted into `games`.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone the data is not duplicate, the historys colums in each table have different information and data in them

Comment: @Ausghostdog - So that is as it should. Why do you want do fetch the data? For which purpose / in which situation?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I added images of the tables data to show you as well. I just want a simple search page for a website I am playing around with for a personal project that a user enters data in to a search feild. An sql query then looks at the tables and gets the relevant data, for example a user searchs vault 13, it returns, fallout 1 and 2 and the history of the vault.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining the tables why not try to add them to an array?

1. create an array with the elements you need to display (don't forget to add the same number of elements from all tables (not 3 from 1 table and 4 from the other)
2. query the first table and use add it to the array
3. query the the second table and add it to the array
4. continue adding the tables you need
5. display the array

Edit:

The array could consist of 4 elements:

1. vault_number
2. name
3. history
4. type (table it's comming from)

example query would be:

```
select vault_number, charactor_name as name, history, 'charactor' as type from charactor


select vault_number, group_name as name, history, 'group' as type from groups
```

You just continue adding this to your array and you can then display all results

---

Take into consideration what Quasimodo's clone explained about your db normalization and the approach given by Sgt AJ could go a long way.